# Perl opendir() only allows one operation?

Tags: files, directory, perl

I've found a strange issue with perl's `opendir()` function that makes absolutely zero sense to me.

In the following example perl will open the directory specified by $path and pull out all of the subdirectory names:

```
opendir(my $dh, $path) or die "can't opendir $path: $!";
my @dirs = grep { ! /^[\.]{1,2}$/ && -d "$path/$_" } readdir($dh);
closedir($dh);
foreach my $d (@dirs) {
   print $encoder->encode($d);
}
```

In this example, perl will open the directory specified by $path and pull out all of the file names:

```
opendir(my $dh, $path) or die "can't opendir $path: $!";
my @files = grep { ! /^[\.]{1,2}$/ && -f "$path/$_" } readdir($dh);
closedir($dh);
foreach my $f (@files) {
   print $encoder->encode($f);
}
```

However, I have found that the following code **ONLY** prints the directories:

```
opendir(my $dh, $path) or die "can't opendir $path: $!";
my @dirs = grep { ! /^[\.]{1,2}$/ && -d "$path/$_" } readdir($dh);
my @files = grep { ! /^[\.]{1,2}$/ && -f "$path/$_" } readdir($dh);
closedir($dh);

foreach my $f (@files) {
   print $encoder->encode($f);
}
foreach my $d (@dirs) {
   print $encoder->encode($d);
}
```

When switching the two `grep` lines in the example above, so that perl assigns `@files` first, perl will **ONLY** print the files.

**WTF?!**

I found a workaround to make it print both files and directories with the following code:

```
opendir(my $dh, $path) or die "can't opendir $path: $!";
my @dirs = grep { ! /^[\.]{1,2}$/ && -d "$path/$_" } readdir($dh);
closedir($dh);

opendir(my $dh, $path) or die "can't opendir $path: $!";
my @files = grep { ! /^[\.]{1,2}$/ && -f "$path/$_" } readdir($dh);
closedir($dh);

foreach my $f (@files) {
   print $encoder->encode($f);
}
foreach my $d (@dirs) {
   print $encoder->encode($d);
}
```

But although I can get my script to work, I still have no idea **why** perl is behaving in the way that it is here. From my understanding, `opendir()` opens a directory and assigns a handle to the first parameter, which is closed by `closedir()`. So, if this is the case, why in the heck can I not do multiple operations with `$dh` if the handle was never closed?

**Extra info:**

```
$ perl --version
This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 1 (v5.26.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

I am running this code on Linux Subsystem for Windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use [**`rewinddir`**](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rewinddir.html) between the two scans.

Perl's directory-scanning functions (like a lot of other things in Perl) is a thin layer over the C runtime.  [Opening](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html) a directory stream lets you [read the entries](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) in a directory, either one or more at a time.  But once read, those are **done**.  If you want to read the directory again, `rewinddir` is the thing to do.

For comparison, here are links to the POSIX (C) [`opendir`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/opendir.html), [`readdir`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html) and [`rewinddir`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rewinddir.html).

Comment: Ah, now this makes sense. `opendir()` works like a C seek operation. Can you provide more detail as to why `rewinddir` is needed and what it does though? It's obvious to me now, but others who stumble across this with a similar issue may not understand.